# jquery console error with reading top property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I struggle with some problem. I have jquery code and I get error: ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.*** I can't fix that.

my code

```
<script>
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        }, 300);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: post html markup also

Comment: Come on! you can't get `offset().top` of a `href`

Comment: @Mr.x: If the `href` is a hash fragment link, it's also an ID selector. E.g., `<a href="#foo">...</a>` means `.attr("href")` is `"#foo"` which would select an element with `id="foo"`. Not all that uncommon.

Comment: When it possible to use `$(this).offset().top` or `$('a#someId').offset().top` why should use `href` , sounds like it's a bad way to selecting an element! @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Mr.x: `$(this).offset().top` would tell you where the top of the *link* is. `$($(this).attr("href")).offset().top` tells you where the top of *the element it links to* is. Again, this isn't unusual at all. The only problem here is that the OP is using it on a link where the `#whatever` doesn't have a matching element in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason `offset` returns `undefined` is if you call it on an empty jQuery set. That tells us that `$($(this).attr('href'))` isn't finding any elements — e.g., `$(this).attr('href')` doesn't match any elements as of when it runs.

Comment: ***sigh*** What, exactly, is "not useful" above?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding(because no HTML markup) your `href` value does not have the value with the `#` symbol like below.

```
 <a href="top">LINK</a>
```

In the above case, your code will give the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` in console. See the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jbubkgrz/). It is because the code is execute like `$('top').offset.top()` which is obviously through error.

You have to add `#` in your `href` element or in your jquery code like below.

```
 <a href="#top">LINK</a>
```

or

```
  $('a').click(function(){        
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 300);
    return false;
});
```

You can check out the updated [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jbubkgrz/2/) here.

**Code Snippet Below.**

```js
$('a').click(function(){        
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        }, 300);
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="top">LINK</a>
<p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p><p>something goes here</p>
<div id="top">
THis is the main div
</div>
```

Comment: Agreed. You're speculating as to the cause of the href selector not matching, but it's reasonable speculation. Nothing here to downvote.